# AttributeError: 'str' object has no attribute 'get'

Tags: python, json

Не могу понять в чем заключается ошибка. Пытаюсь распарсить ответ json, вот представленный код:

```
acc_response = requests.post(url=url, headers=headers, data=json.dumps(requestDomainAcc))
res = acc_response.json()['AccountTree']
result = []
for c in res:
    c_root = c.get('root').strip()
    c_items = c.get('items').strip()
    for item in c_items:
        item_employee_id = item.get('employee_id').strip()
        item_display_name = item.get('display_name').strip()
        item_login = item.get('login').strip()
        item_last_activity_utc_time = item.get('last_activity_utc_time').strip()
        item_is_enabled = item.get('is_enabled').strip()

        result.append(
            [item_employee_id, item_display_name, item_login, item_last_activity_utc_time, item_is_enabled]
        )
```

В ответ выдает:

```
    c_root = c.get('root').strip()
AttributeError: 'str' object has no attribute 'get'
```

Ответ json (acc_response) из себя представляет словарь.

upd: для уточнения прикреплю часть запроса, из которого запрашиваются данные

```
requestDomainAcc = 

{
    "controller": "BatchProcessing",
    "session": token_session,
    "query": {
        "items": [
            {
                "name": "AccountTree",
                "controller": "account_tree",
                "params": {
                    "name_filter": {
                        "name": ""
                    }
                }
            }
        ]
    }
}
```

res ответ:

```
{
    "AccountTree": {
        "root": {
            "items": [
                {
                    "domain_id": 1,
                    "name": "int.mum.com",
                    "last_sync_time": 0,
                    "is_sync_struct": 1,
                    "organization_units": "",
                    "auth_exist": 0,
                    "items": [
                        {
                            "account_id": 1,
                            "is_master": 1,
                            "login": "v.shkysh",
                            "display_name": "Шукшин Серега",
                            "last_activity_utc_time": 1661259936,
                            "employee": {
                                "employee_id": 2,
                                "display_name": "Шукшин Серега"
                            },
                            "is_single_link": 1
                        }
                    ]
                },
                {
                    "domain_id": 2,
                    "name": "vl.contoso.com",
                    "last_sync_time": 0,
                    "is_sync_struct": 0,
                    "organization_units": "",
                    "auth_exist": 0,
                    "items": [
                        {
                            "account_id": 5,
                            "is_master": 1,
                            "login": "Administrator",
                            "display_name": "Administrator",
                            "last_activity_utc_time": 1661257338,
                            "employee": {
                                "employee_id": 6,
                                "display_name": "Administrator"
                            },
                            "is_single_link": 1
                        },
```

Comment: Что такое `res`?

Comment: отредактировал вопрос, надеюсь стало более менее понятно

Comment: Если `res` это словарь, то значит при запихивании его в цикл значения `c` будут ключами этого словаря, то есть строками (`"root"` и так далее), а у строк не бывает метода `get`

Comment: интересует возможное решение проблемы, если у кого есть идеи, потому что я туплю на этом моменте конкретно

Comment: А можно кусок `res` в вопрос добавить?

Comment: Можете зазвездиь все данные что "не для всех" просто структура нужна

Comment: добавил res в вопрос, некоторые скобки недописал, в целом не критично, скопировал не весь ответ

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`pip install jmespath`

```
data = {
    "AccountTree": {
        "root": {
            "items": [
                {
                    "domain_id": 1,
                    "name": "int.mum.com",
                    "last_sync_time": 0,
                    "is_sync_struct": 1,
                    "organization_units": "",
                    "auth_exist": 0,
                    "items": [
                        {
                            "account_id": 1,
                            "is_master": 1,
                            "login": "v.shkysh",
                            "display_name": "Шукшин Серега",
                            "last_activity_utc_time": 1661259936,
                            "employee": {
                                "employee_id": 2,
                                "display_name": "Шукшин Серега"
                            },
                            "is_single_link": 1
                        }
                    ]
                },
                {
                    "domain_id": 2,
                    "name": "vl.contoso.com",
                    "last_sync_time": 0,
                    "is_sync_struct": 0,
                    "organization_units": "",
                    "auth_exist": 0,
                    "items": [
                        {
                            "account_id": 5,
                            "is_master": 1,
                            "login": "Administrator",
                            "display_name": "Administrator",
                            "last_activity_utc_time": 1661257338,
                            "employee": {
                                "employee_id": 6,
                                "display_name": "Administrator"
                            },
                            "is_single_link": 1
                        },
                        {
                            "account_id": 6,
                            "is_master": 1,
                            "login": "Administrator",
                            "display_name": "Administrator",
                            "last_activity_utc_time": 1661257558,
                            "employee": {
                                "employee_id": 8,
                                "display_name": "Administrator"
                            },
                            "is_single_link": 1
                        }
                    ]
                }
            ]
        }
    }
}
```

```py
import jmespath as jp

print(
    jp.search(
        'AccountTree.root.items[*].items[*][employee.employee_id,employee.display_name,login,last_activity_utc_time,is_single_link][]',
         data
    )
)
# [[2, 'Шукшин Серега', 'v.shkysh', 1661259936, 1], [6, 'Administrator', 'Administrator', 1661257338, 1], [8, 'Administrator', 'Administrator', 1661257558, 1]]
```

#### UPD:

Если использовать другой паттерн то можно на выходе получить список словарей:

```py
pprint(
    jp.search(
        'AccountTree.root.items[*].items[*].{employee_id:employee.employee_id,display_name:employee.display_name,login:login,last_activity_utc_time:last_activity_utc_time,is_single_link:is_single_link}[]',
         data
    )
)
```

Даст на выходе

```latex
[{'display_name': 'Шукшин Серега',
  'employee_id': 2,
  'is_single_link': 1,
  'last_activity_utc_time': 1661259936,
  'login': 'v.shkysh'},
 {'display_name': 'Administrator',
  'employee_id': 6,
  'is_single_link': 1,
  'last_activity_utc_time': 1661257338,
  'login': 'Administrator'},
 {'display_name': 'Administrator',
  'employee_id': 8,
  'is_single_link': 1,
  'last_activity_utc_time': 1661257558,
  'login': 'Administrator'}]
```

> А за ошибку Вам в коментариях правильно ответили, при итерации по словарю, в переменную попадает значение ключа. Для того, чтобы итерировать по ключам и значениям, то итерацию нужно делать по `for key, value in var.items():`